# Is Baba Lysaga meant to have resistance to magic?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, published-adventures, curse-of-strahd

In the *Curse of Strahd* campaign, the description of [Baba Lysaga](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/cos/appendix-d-monsters-and-npcs#BabaLysaga) (pages 228-229) includes the following text for one of her features/abilities (emphasis mine):

> ***Gifts of Mother Night.*** The goddess Mother Night has bestowed magical gifts on Baba Lysaga as rewards for her ceaseless devotion to Strahd. **Her skin has the resilience of stone, she is resistant to harmful magic, and she is shielded against divination magic.**

However, within [Baba Lysaga](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/baba-lysaga)'s stat block itself, there is no mention of her resilient skin and resistance to magic. In fact, the name of the feature that protects against divination magic is slightly different, too:

> ***Blessing of Mother Night.*** Baba Lysaga is shielded against divination magic, as though protected by a *nondetection* spell.

Is there errata or clarification somewhere as to whether or not this character is supposed to have some additional defenses within her stat block? The CR11 suggests that she's meant to be tougher to kill.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### According to designer Chris Perkins, her statblock is correct.

Chris Perkins, lead designer of *Curse of Strahd*, addressed this question in [a September 2016 tweet](https://twitter.com/ChrisPerkinsDnD/status/781530748767444993):

> *In Baba Lysaga's write up she has magic res. and the resilience of stone. Don't see it in her statblock. Which is correct?*
>
> **Both. Her AC accounts for her unnatural resilience.**

When the adventure text says "Her skin has the resilience of stone, [and] she is resistant to harmful magic", ostensibly this corresponds to [Baba Lysaga](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/baba-lysaga)'s AC of 15 (hence the parenthetical noting that this is "natural armor"). This fits the description of her skin, though it's not clear how AC alone indicates her being "resistant to harmful magic".

That said, in addition to her Intelligence score of 20, she also has a Wisdom score of 17 (a +3 modifier); she's also proficient in Wisdom saving throws, bringing her total modifier for Wis saves to +7. She also seems to have the equivalent of expertise (double-proficiency) in both Arcana and Religion, giving her a total modifier of +13 for both skills. Together with her AC, it seems reasonable to interpret this as giving her some ability to identify magic/spells and a form of defense against it.

Comment: Yeesh. CR11 and my party of level 8 characters took her out in the first round of combat. /Shrug. Guess it shows how subjective the challenge rating system gets to be at higher levels.

Comment: @Rykara not really. If she was the only threat in the encounter that obviously wouldn't work very well, doesn't matter how strong she is she's still subject to action economy.